# Sequence of Javascript/Jquery function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand more deeply how `javascript` works. 
I have this piece of code:

```
 var string = [];

 var retrieve = $(".highlightPlugin").each(function(i, e){
                  $e = $(e).find('.item');
                  $e.each(function(){
                    string.push("#"+this.id);
                  })
                }).promise();

console.log(string); // ['1', '2', '3', .. ]

retrive.done(function(){ console.log(string); }); // ['1', '2', '3', .. ]
```

Both the `console.log(string)` are loggin the right `values`, the `string` `Array` is correctly populated.

What I was asking to myself: is this a case or not? 
I'm asking this because, as far as I know, execution of `code`s in javascript is kind of `asynchronous`. Am I wrong?

Please tell me if I was not clear.

Comment: *is this a case or not?* ... what does that mean?

Comment: The code is only async when you have an async method.

Comment: The promise is useless in this case..

Comment: @Pointy is a case that `string` is correctly logged in both `console.log`

Comment: execution of js is *synchronous*, however, there are some *asynchronous* things about some js calls. For example, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` will affect code execution order. Also, making ajax calls

Comment: `each()` is not asynchronous so your above code is running in the order you've coded it.  Put a `setInterval()` in the `each()` function and you'll see that the first `console.log` will be incomplete.

Comment: @CrayonViolent ok, that's more clear now, Thank you.

Comment: Oh OK - well like others have said, JavaScript is asynchronous when it's asynchronous; it's not so much about the *language* as it is about the runtime system and the external facilities you're using.